# SMS default contact name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms

Whenever I receive a text message from some services (namely Google and Blablacar), I see the service name as the sender (like if it was in my contacts) instead of an ugly phone number, as it appears when the text message comes from other services (Snapchat, Hello Bank).

[image: I think a picture will help to understand]

I don't know if an app from the service needs to be installed on the iPhone for the service name to appear instead of the phone number : I have the BlaBlaCar app installed and (of course) one of the Google apps (Maps), but the sms from Google was to confirm my phone number as I created a google account my computer, not on my phone. So the text message cannot "come from" the iOS app.

When I click the sender "Contact" button and then the Info icon, I can see the real sender phone number (ex 4 66 45 3 for google and 2 52 25 22 27 for blablacar).

I have never added those phone numbers to my contacts myself, neither I see those "contacts" in my contacts.

**I would like to know how it is made, so I can do the same when sending a text message from my server.**

Are there some kind of pre-embedded default hidden contacts in iOS ?

Is there a field to fill in the app plist file like "default app phone number" that I didn't see ?

Is it some kind of a registration process with Apple so you can associate a phone number to a specific name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was looking in the wrong direction, this has nothing to do with iOS, Apple, or an iOS app setting, this is a feature of the Short Message System called **Sender ID**.

Here is a thread which lead me to the answer : http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/109878-How-to-Send-SMS-with-Sender-Name

This ability to set the sender ID is offered by many of the SMS sending platforms (Clickatell, SMSCountry, blastSMS...), but apparently it might not work in every country.

Here you can find some info about it : http://www.smscountry.com/custom-sender-id.aspx

Hope it will help if someone wonders like me "How hell Google has put itself into my contacts ?" !

Comment: Apparently you can set this Sender ID to anything you want (there is just a limit in the number of characters allowed). There is no need for the equivalent of a SSL certificate (so you can proove you are the owner of the name you set) even if the SMS sending platform you use may check it. I find it a little unsafe, what if anyone can send me a text message saying they are Google or my bank ?